# send signal to command pipe tears down whole pipe

Tags: pipe, signals

I have a simple example of two processes

the first is a simple loop which does some processing

```
#!/bin/bash
function signalHandler() {
    echo "sig: $1 received ==> exit"
    for i in {1..5}; do
        echo "cleanup $i %"
        sleep 1
    done
    trap SIGINT
    kill -INT $$
}

trap signalHandler SIGUSR2

for i in {1..100000}; do
    echo "doing stuff $i %"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

I launched the script like so:

```
./script.sh | grep "wow"
```

where I attached an auxiliary grep command just for demonstration.

When I send a USR2 signal to the `grep` process (`kill USR2 $(pgrep grep)`) only, the whole pipe gets torn down (?). Why is `script.sh` not continuing?

Secondly, when I send a USR2 signal to the whole process group (something  like `kill USR2 -$!`) , obviously the same happens, since `grep` quits fast, it tears down the whole pipe without letting `script.sh` executing the `signalHandler`.
I think I have some misunderstanding how that should work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: My guess is that `grep` gets the signal, quits, closes the pipe, and the script gets SIGPIPE, which it isn't handling and dies.

Comment: when I replace the script.sh with a C++ program which does not handle SIGPIPE (`signal.h`) does it also die?

Comment: @Gabriel I'm not sure about C++, but in C, you can ignore the signal with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` . You'd need to check for errors returned by write operations to STDOUT though to detect whether the pipe no longer exists.

Comment: @Gabriel see my updated answer below for how to suppress the signal and its error messages in the script completely.

Answer (score 5):

As @muru commented, the problem is that your script does not handle `SIGPIPE`.

The following changes will allow the script to terminate as intended:

```
function signalHandler() {
    echo "sig: $1 received ==> exit" >&2   # <--
    for i in {1..5}; do
        echo "cleanup $i %" >&2   # <--
        sleep 1
    done
    trap SIGINT
    kill -INT $$
}

trap signalHandler SIGUSR2
trap signalHandler SIGPIPE   # <--
```

To keep the example simple, the same signal handler is used to handle `SIGPIPE`. The `echo` output of the signal handler is redirected to `STDERR`, since `STDOUT` obviously already is broken by the time the `SIGPIPE`is trapped.

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh | grep wow
./script.sh: line 16: echo: write error: Broken pipe
sig:  received ==> exit
cleanup 1 %
cleanup 2 %
cleanup 3 %
cleanup 4 %
cleanup 5 %

User defined signal 2: 31
```

The pipe breaks (first error message), but the signal handler completea before `script.sh` exits.

If you want to ignore the `SIGPIPE` completely, you'd need to add a dummy handler for the signal, and redirect STDERR for the main `echo` statement to `/dev/null`:

```
function signalHandler2() {
    :
}

trap signalHandler SIGUSR2
trap signalHandler2 SIGPIPE

# ...skip...

for i in {1..100000}; do
    echo "doing stuff $i %" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: why is stdout already broken thats strange? because of the pipe?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes… the stdout of `script.sh` goes into the pipe. As `grep` gets killed, the pipe breaks. This event triggers the `SIGPIPE`, but the pipe is already broken at this moment so the script can no longer write to it by the time the signal handler executes.

Comment: Thanks, another question arises, why the hack is the default action for SIGPIPE that it kills the process? (in that case `script.sh) Thanks for clarification =)

Comment: Found it: https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=show